# Validating multiple inputs procured through read command

Tags: shell, validation, input, ksh

I am trying to validate multiple inputs separated by spaces(two disk names in the below case) with a shell script. But, I am un-successful in doing so. Can someone help me?

```
read DISK
if [ "${1}" = "" ] || [ "${2}" = "" ]
then
printf "The Disk pairs cannot be left blank. Exiting script!!!"
exit 1
else
TMP=$DISK
printf "The disks entered are $TMP"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ksh93, you can use

```
read -A disks
if [[ ${#disks[@]} -ne 2 ]]; then
    print -u2 "You need to enter 2 disks" 
    exit 1
else
    print "You entered: ${disks[*]}"
fi
```

For ksh88, use the positional parameters

```
read disks
set -- $disks
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    print -u2 "You need to enter 2 disks" 
    exit 1
else
    print "You entered: $disks"
fi
```

Comment: It did work out. But can you let me know the pupose you have used set --

Comment: That invokation of `set`, with no other `±options`, sets the [positional parameters](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html#Parameter%20Substitution) to the values you provide. So now, `$1` is the first word, `$2` is the second word, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `${1}` and `${2}` are the commandline parameters and are unrelated to the last read command. There are different ways to use the DISK variable.
Once you have the DISK variable read, I would have chosen for a solution like

```
echo "${DISK}" | while read disk1 disk2 otherfields; do
   echo "disk1=${disk1}, disk2=${disk2}"
done
# or better
disk1="${DISK% *}"; echo "${disk1}"
disk2="${DISK#* }"; echo "${disk2}"
# or worse
disk1=$(echo "${DISK}" | cut -d" " -f1)
disk2=$(echo "${DISK}" | cut -d" " -f2)
```

When you already know you want to split the fields, you can change your first read command. Replace `read DISK` with

```
read disk1 disk2 remaining_input
```